# OpenCV C++ ,Collision for Retangle and line

Tags: c++, opencv, collision

[Please Click! Image for Pedestrians and line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTizZ.png)

Hello, guys
You guys can see Pedestrians with Rectangle and line middle on video.
I used cascade training for detecting pedestrian.(CascadeClassifier).

I want to detect the collison with Rectangle(pedestrian) and line.
When the collision is detected, I want to change the Rectangle's color.
Here is some code I wrote. 
Please Check and let me know how I detect collsion.
I'm using C++ and Opencv 2.4.9.

Appreciate.

```
cv::Size min_obj_sz(47,65);
cv::Size max_obj_sz(80,100);
int width,height;
cv::Mat frame,gray_frame;
__int64 freq,start,finish;
::QueryPerformanceFrequency((_LARGE_INTEGER*)&freq);


videoCapture >> frame;

frameImage = ImageFormat::Mat2QImage(frame);
Origin_videoFrameLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(frameImage));
cvtColor(frame, gray_frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
::QueryPerformanceCounter((_LARGE_INTEGER*)&start);



cv::vector<cv::Rect> found;


detector.detectMultiScale(
            gray_frame,
            found,
            1.1,
            1,
            CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,

            min_obj_sz,
            max_obj_sz
            );

// processing time (fps)
::QueryPerformanceCounter((_LARGE_INTEGER*)&finish);
double fps = freq / double(finish - start + 1);
char fps_str[20];
sprintf_s(fps_str, 20, "FPS: %.1lf", fps);
putText(frame, fps_str, cv::Point(5, 35), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1., cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2);

// draw results (bounding boxes)
width=(frame.cols);
height=frame.rows;
line(frame, cv::Point(0, width/2), cv::Point(width,height/2),cv::Scalar(94, 206, 165),3,2);

for(int i=0; i<(int)found.size(); i++)
    rectangle(frame, found[i], cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2);

cvtColor(frame, gray_frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
if(gray_convert == true) frameImage = ImageFormat::Mat2QImage(frame);
else frameImage = ImageFormat::MatGray2QImage(gray_frame);

videoFrameLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(frameImage));
```

Comment: you can choose 4 parametrized lines (left/right/top/bottom of the rectangle) then compute the intersection of your line with those lines. If they intersect within the parameter range of the rectangle border, your line collides with the rectangle. Easier to implement would be a mask approach: draw your line on a 0 valued CV_8UC1 mask Mat, then use `cv::countNonZero(mask(rectangle))` if that is `> 0` then your rectangle intersects the line.

Comment: can you show me the code adapted to my code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be try to intersect the line with the 4 edges of the bounding box, if any of them intersects with the line, then there is a collision. Now how do we intersect a line with a edge? Here is an example that might help explain

[image: Figure]

In the above figure, the black box is your bounding box, if you extend the left edge (blue line), then there are only three cases that could happen to any line in the image with the blue line
1) The line is parallel to the blue line
2) The line intersects with the blue line, but the intersection is not on the black edge (red line)
3) The line intersects with the blue line and the intersection is on the black edge (green line)

So let's say you have your line represented by two points `p1` and `p2`, we can write the collision test function like this

```
//! Test if a line (with a point p(x1, y2) and slope k) intersects with a line segment (x, min_y) -> (x, max_y)
bool intersect(const double x1, const double y1, const double k, const double x, const double min_y, const double max_y)
{
  double y = y1 + (x - x1) * k;
  return (y >= min_y && y <= max_y);
}

bool collision_detection(const cv::Point& p1, const cv::Point& p2, const cv::Rect& r)
{
  // Vertical line
  if (p1.x == p2.x) {
    return (p1.x >= r.x && p1.x < r.x+r.width);
  }
  // Horizontal line
  else if (p1.y == p2.y) {
    return (p1.y >= r.y && p1.y < r.y+r.height);
  }
  // General case
  double k = (p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x);
  // Test left edge
  if (intersect(p1.x, p1.y, k, r.x, r.y, r.y+r.height-1)) {
    return true;
  }
  // Test right edge
  if (intersect(p1.x, p1.y, k, r.x+r.width-1, r.y, r.y+r.height-1)) {
    return true;
  }
  // We can reuse the intersect function if we swap x and y
  double k_inv = (p2.x - p1.x) / (p2.y - p1.y);
  // Test top edge
  if (intersect(p1.y, p1.x, k_inv, r.y, r.x, r.x+r.width-1)) {
    return true;
  }
  // Test bottom edge
  if (intersect(p1.y, p1.x, k_inv, r.y+r.height-1, r.x, r.x+r.width-1)) {
    return true;
  }
  // All failed, no collision
  return false;
}
```